# Pytorch - Indexing a range of multiple Indices?

Tags: pytorch

Lets say I have a tensor of size [100, 100] and I have a set of `start_indices` and `end_indices` of size [100]

I want to be able to do something like this:

`tensor[start_indices:end_indices, :] = 0`

Unfortunately, I get an error saying

`TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index`

So is this actually possible without a for loop?

Answer (score 5):

Without loops of any kind

```
mytensor = torch.randn(4, 10)
start = torch.tensor([1, 3, 1, 3]).unsqueeze(-1)
end = torch.tensor([3, 5, 7, 4]).unsqueeze(-1)
```

create an array of indices in the same shape as the tensor you want to index

```
index = torch.arange(10).repeat(4).reshape(4, 10)
>>> index

tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Then simply convert to a boolean mask

```
gte_start = start <= index
lt_end = index < end
mask = gte_start & lt_end
>>> mask
tensor([[False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

and apply it

```
mytensor[mask] = 42.0
```

masks are my go-to for multi-dimensional operations if looping is undesirable (which it often is)

Comment: Excellent solution to a surprisingly irritating problem. I have been struggling to create masks from bounding box extents. I should note though that there is a small problem with your output. `lt_end` should be False for row 0, col 3.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible without some sort of loop or list comprehension.

Below are some alternatives which may be useful depending on your use-case. Specifically if you are looking to reuse the same `start_indices` and `end_indices` for multiple assignments, or if you are looking have only one in-place assignment to `tensor` then the solutions below would be useful.

---

If instead of `start_indices` and `end_indices` you were given a list of indices, for example

```
row_indices = torch.cat([torch.arange(s, e, dtype=torch.int64) for s, e in zip(start_indices, end_indices)])
```

Then this would be possible using

```
tensor[row_indices, :] = 0
```

---

Or if you were given a mask

```
mask = torch.zeros(tensor.shape, dtype=torch.bool, device=tensor.device)
for s, e in zip(start_indices, end_indices):
    mask[s:e, :] = True
```

then this would be possible using

```
tensor[mask] = 0
```

Comment: doesnt ath still require a for loop. This part is really slow. I want to avoid for loops if possible

Comment: Yes as indicated in the beginning of my answer, to the best of my knowledge pytorch doesn't support indexing with multiple start/end indicies for the same dimension and any solution would require some form of loop. The solutions provided here may be useful if you don't need to compute the indices for every iteration but won't necessarily be faster in general.

Comment: I ended up writing my own cuda kernel and it's basically 30x faster

Comment: yeah I was thinking of mentioning that as a potential solution but didn't have the time to actually write one. If possible, could post your cuda kernal as an answer to your question? It would be quite useful!

Comment: sorry but its quite domain specific. i could probably write a generalized one at some point

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on @jodag's answer:

Using `torch.cat` to create the combined range first (even if they overlap) seems to be some 30% faster than a simple for loop. My tests indicate this holds over a wide range of values for `n_ranges` (I tried from 100 to 10,000):

```py
tensor_size = 100
n_ranges = 10000
start_indices = [random.randint(0, tensor_size // 2) for _ in range(n_ranges)]
end_indices = [start_indices[i] + random.randint(1, tensor_size // 2) for i in range(n_ranges)]
```

```py
# 32 milliseconds for this line
row_indices = torch.cat([torch.arange(s, e, dtype=torch.int64)
                        for s, e in zip(start_indices, end_indices)])
# and 3 milliseconds for this line
tensor[row_indices, :] = 0
```

```py
# 45 milliseconds for this loop; an increase of 28%
for s, e in zip(start_indices, end_indices):
    tensor[s:e, :] = 0
```

The mask method, surprisingly, is a further 11% time increase compared to the simple `for` loop when `n_ranges = 100` but is 5% faster at `n_ranges = 10000`.