# pytorch multi hot vectors

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to implement a multi-hot vector in PyTorch.

1. create a zero tensor of size len(x) x (multi_hot_num * max_num)
2. Then, for each element in 'x', fill the corresponding range of indices from x[i] * multi_hot_num to (x[i]+1) * multi_hot_num in the tensor with 1.

The following code succinctly demonstrates the desired behavior:

```py
max_num = 4
multi_hot_num = 3
x = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1])
```

expect output:

```py
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0]])
```

So my question is, how to create an expected output using x, max_num, and multi_hot_num.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to find an optimized way without loop, but it seems like using loop is the only solution (to the best of my knowledge).

```py
import torch

max_num = 4
multi_hot_num = 3
x = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1])

assert torch.all(x < max_num)

result = torch.zeros(len(x), max_num*multi_hot_num)
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(x*multi_hot_num, (x+1)*multi_hot_num)):
    result[i, start:end] = 1.
    
print(result)
```

Result:

```py
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

## EDITED: without for loop

Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998769/10732351)

```py
import torch

max_num = 4
multi_hot_num = 3
x = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1])

assert torch.all(x < max_num)

start = (x * multi_hot_num).unsqueeze(-1)
end = ((x+1) * multi_hot_num).unsqueeze(-1)

result = torch.zeros(len(x), max_num*multi_hot_num)
index = torch.arange(max_num*multi_hot_num).unsqueeze(0).repeat(len(x), 1)

gte_start = start <= index
lt_end = index < end
mask = gte_start & lt_end
result[mask]=1

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! But I wish there was no for statement.

Comment: In that case, I just update my answer, that solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998769/10732351).